# How to work with more Target.Address (range)

Tags: excel, vba

In a cell, I have made a list to choose. However, one choice is not enough. I found some vba code that enables me to make more choices. But this code points to a specific cell. I want to use it more general in the sheet, probably a range.

I tried to put in a range as `target.address` but that won't work. It won't work with a range of one cell (J3) either. I found out that the formula below does not work after removing the dollar signs from `$j$3`.

```
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String


On Error GoTo Exitsub
TheCell = ActiveCell

If Target.Address = "$J$13" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I look for a solution to choose from all the list of more than one item. The formula should be changed in a way that is usable in a range of cells. These cells have al the same choice list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
If Target.Address = "$J$13" Then
```

You can do an [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) of your `Target` range with the range you like to check:

```
Dim AffectedRange As Range
Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J13:J20")) 'put your range here

If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In AffectedRange 'loop through all affected cells
        'here use Cell instead of Target
    Next Cell

End If
```